How can i get all values in a web request with powershell?
I have a web request that i send to powershell
 Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $result

There should be a filed called "output" that has a number of fields.
I have tried the below
((Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $result) |ConvertFrom-Json) | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 
   output.Count

it says output.Count doesnt exist. output is returned as null. But if i do it in postman , output has values .
Why would this be happening ?

If you’re reading json from a web  api use Invoke-RestMethod instead of Invoke-WebRequest - it’ll return structured pscustomobjects with properties you can work with rather than textual content. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7.4 for details.

I just tried that and the result is as below :    @{name=runid;  timeStatus=Running; input=; customDetails=; output=;}   Notice how they are empty?

Postman actually gives data in "output"

That’s what happens when you interpolate a nested pscustomobject object into a string - see this for example $x = [pscustomobject] @{ "aaa" = "bbb"; "ccc" = [pscustomobject] @{ "ddd" = "eee" } }; "$x" which displays @{aaa=bbb; ccc=}. Notice how “ccc” is shown “empty” here but actually has a value in the variable (try $x.ccc.ddd to see the output eee) - that’s a limitation of how Powershell serialises the structured value into a string.

Is output.Count a property named "output.Count", a property named "output" that has a count sub property, or is it meant to be 2 properties as in output, Count?  If the period is part of the properties name, then you may need to enclose it in quotes.
